# Distribution of future value of equal cash-flows with log-normal returns

Tags: distributions, lognormal-distribution, sum

If I'm making equal payments $C$ each period into an investment with log-normal one period returns such that $r_i \sim N(\mu, \sigma)$, is there a simple way to derive the distribution of future wealth at some time $T$?

I think terminal wealth should follow a function like this, because each cash flow grows with the remaining time (deposits made at the start of each time)

\begin{align}
  C \sum_{t=1}^T \exp(\sum_{i=t}^T(r_i))
\end{align}

i.e. I am interested in the distribution of that sum, which is a sum of log-normal RVs -- however, they are not iid.

Given these conditions, can we say something intelligent about the approximate distribution of terminal wealth? Does it matter if $r_i$ are iid?